# When to pass T*& p instead of T* p?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I would like to understand the difference between passing `*&p` and `*p` and when to use one over another.

Say, I have a init function like the following.

```
void init(lua_State *L) {
    L = luaL_newstate(); //allocate new memory to L
}
```

And in `main()` if I try to access to `L`, it crashes.

```
lua_State *L;
init(L);
do_something(L);//crash
```

However, when I change the argument type to `lua_State *&L`, it no longer crashes.

Is it because allocating new memory changes value of pointer?

If so, isn't it better and safe to always pass with `*&` instead of `*`?

Is there any general rule about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between pointer-to-pointer vs reference-to-pointer (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424132/difference-between-pointer-to-pointer-vs-reference-to-pointer-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ passing by const pointer or reference to const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788157/c-passing-by-const-pointer-or-reference-to-const-pointer)

Comment: You are passing `L` in this example. Do you actually mean to ask about the difference in *parameter type* `T *p` versus `T *&p` ?

Comment: @juanchopanza [yes, it would](https://ideone.com/UP215y)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I let myself get confused by the confusing title, which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to understand the difference between passing *&p and *p and when to use one over another.

Your objective is to change the value of `L` in `init` and make sure that the change is visible in the calling function.

Passing a pointer to `init` does not work because any changes to the argument is only a local change. It does not change the value of the variable in the calling function. Hence, the pointer remains uninitialized in `main`. Using the uninitialized pointer in `main` leads to undefined behavior, which manifests as a crash on your system.

I suggest changing the argument type of `init` to a reference to a pointer. When you do that, any changes to the argument will be visible in the calling function.

```
void init(lua_State*& L) {
    L = luaL_newstate(); //allocate new memory to L
    // The new value of L will be visible in the calling function.
}
```

and use it as

```
lua_State *L;
init(L);
do_something(L);
```

Suggestion for better coding practice - always initialize your automatic variables at the point of declaration.

```
lua_State* L = nullptr;
init(L);
do_something(L);
```

Comment: @ZackLee To avoid such crashing, you can always do this: `if(L) do_something(L);`. by which you can check whether pointer holds anything/ initialized.

Comment: @JeJo that will only work if the pointer is initialized. In the OP's code, it wasn't, so the behavior of such an `if` would be undefined

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes true. I had initialised `lua_State* L = nullptr;` before checking.      Forgot to mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a variable `int p`, then `&p` means the address of `p`, finally *&p = p, the value of `p`

Now consider a variable `int *p`, then p points to the address of `p`, and `*p` is the value of the variable